# .hpp file producing errors. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files

I'm trying to use an hpp file for 3D Perlin Noise found here: https://github.com/Reputeless/PerlinNoise

I've followed the installation instructions, and added the file to the project using the solution explorer, but Visual Studio lists errors in the PerlinNoise.hpp file. Specifically, these:

SIVPERLIN_CONCEPT_URBG "Namespace "std" has no member "is_invocable" Line 253

SIVPERLIN_CONCEPT_URBG "Namespace "std" has no member "is_invocable" Line 433

SIVPERLIN_CONCEPT_URBG "Namespace "std" has no member "is_invocable" Line 448

I am not too advanced with Visual Studio so I have no clue how I can fix this but I have a feeling it's an installation issue. Any suggestions on what is causing the error and how to get it working?

Thank you in advance.
-Richard

Comment: As stated in the README this header requires modern C++ (C++17/20). Have you enabled C++17 in Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi @Aamir - you are right. I did not know about those differences. I changed it and the errors went away. Thank you. Question: I will need to compile this project on a Mac as well, using XCode, which I have done before with my other projects. Do you think this change to c++ 17 will be an issue on Mac when I need to do that?

Comment: I'm not a MacOS guy, but it depends on the version of the compiler. If you have latest compiler then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aamir pointed out, I had to change my compiler version to (C++17/20). As soon as I did that, the errors disappeared.

Thank you.